# Cannot read xml with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I can read an XML doc using LINQ  when there is no namespace in the root but retrieve nothing when it is present.

The code is used to step through the document:

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Level1").Elements("Level2"))
```

I also tried to get the namespace

```
var ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants(ns + "Level1").Elements("Level2"))
```

The document is set out as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="xmlns://www.example.com/schema/root" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.11" xsi:type="FVDL">
<Level1>
<Level2>
etc
```

Can anyone point our where I am going wrong :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Level2` is in the same namespace as the `Root` and the `Level1` elements (the descendant elements inherit namespaces defined with the `xmlns` attribute until the namespace is redefined) so you need to use `ns +` in both cases i.e.:

```
doc.Descendants(ns + "Level1").Elements(ns + "Level2"))
```

Comment: Brilliant... I had wrongly assumed that once in the namespace at the root, then the child items would be picked up. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default namespace of the root as follows:

```
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

Comment: Nice comment, but that should not be posted as answer

Comment: Well, I think this is the answer of the point where user have tried to get the namespace of the given xml, that's why I have posted it as answer